# get a value from url in php

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, get

i have passed a value through my url by using javascript, and i tried to access that variable in another page by using php `$_POST` but it is not working

```
<a data-room-type-id="<?php echo $rooms->id; ?>" class="btn-book-now" href=""><?php echo $rooms->name; ?></a>
```

I want to transfer the value data-room-type-id, below showing the javascript used for transfer value

```js
tjq('.room-list').on('click', '.btn-book-now', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (acc_data.booking_url) { alert(acc_data.booking_url);
            //var room_type_id = tjq(this).data('room-type-id');
            
            var roomid = tjq(this).data('room-type-id');
            alert("roomid = "+roomid);
            
            var room_type_id = '79';
            alert(room_type_id);
            
            tjq('input[name="action"]').remove();
            //booking_data = tjq("#check_availability_form").serialize();
            
            booking_data = 'accommodation_id=45&_wpnonce=32da73f035&date_from=10%2F26%2F2016&date_to=10%2F28%2F2016&rooms=1&adults=1&kids=0&child_ages%5B%5D=0';
            alert(booking_data);
            
            var form = tjq('<form method="get" action="' + acc_data.booking_url + '"></form>');
            form.append('<input type="hidden" name="booking_data" value="' + booking_data + '&room_type_id=' + room_type_id + '&roomid=' + roomid + '">');
            /*if ( acc_data.lang ) {
                form.append('<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="' + acc_data.lang + '">');
            }*/
            tjq("body").append(form);
            form.submit();
        } else {
            alert(acc_data.msg_no_booking_page);
        }
        return false;
    });
```

and javascript used in the code is above.

but in another page i can't retrieve the value roomid

the url is look this

http://www.medhyaftravel.com/accommodation-booking/?booking_data=accommodation_id%3D45%26_wpnonce%3D32da73f035%26date_from%3D10%252F26%252F2016%26date_to%3D10%252F28%252F2016%26rooms%3D1%26adults%3D1%26kids%3D0%26child_ages%255B%255D%3D0%26room_type_id%3D79%26roomid%3D59903

Comment: check [$_SERVER](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Comment: it is usually done in php by $_GET

Comment: is your url is something like this page.php?id=4  ?

Comment: i have updated my question with the url above

Answer (score 0):

your form is empty remove the ending form tag from var form and at the end after the hidden variables add this as below:

```
var form = tjq('<form method="get" action="' + acc_data.booking_url + '">');
        form.append('<input type="hidden" name="booking_data" value="' + booking_data + '&room_type_id=' + room_type_id + '&roomid=' + roomid + '">');
        form.append('</form>');
```

Comment: my url is passing the variable, above i have modified my question with the url, there i have the roomid and a value with it. but i can't access the variable in another page

Answer (score 0):

Your form uses `method="get"` so `$_POST` is empty. You will only get POST data if the form method is post. For GET request the data will be in `$_GET`. Please read up online on when to use get and when to use post, this is very important

`$_GET['booking_data']` will contain the full booking data string.

This is probebly not what you what. You are adding a get url data to a formfield which the encodes it again.

You either add the get url data directly to the `acc_data.booking_url` used as action. Or create hidden form fields for each entry:

```
form.append('<input type="hidden" name="room_type_id" value="' + room_type_id + '">');
form.append('<input type="hidden" name="roomid" value="' + roomid + '">');
```

And so on for all values

Comment: i have used $_REQUEST also, but I can't read the data, but I can access the other two variable data also, only this I can't

Comment: You need to be more specific. What did you change? What can you read and what not?

Comment: please look on the url i shared, from that i can retrieve all other data, but that roomid which only i can't read.

Comment: Did you do anything with my suggestions? How are you reading the data in php?

Comment: no, i didn't use your suggestion for the result above shown.